# Addidional menu item in Drupal 8

Tags: php, symfony, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to create a module for Drupal 8 and I can't figure out how to add a new item to menu.

In Drupal 7 the code below was enough:

```
function mymodule_menu()
{
$item['admin/settings/mymodule'] = array(
    'title' => 'MyModule',
    'description' => 'MyModule settings',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_settings_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer mymodule'),
    'file' => 'mymodule.settings.inc',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

return $item;
}
```

[image]

New menu item should appear on the bar with `Content` `Structure` etc.

In new Drupal writen in Symfony2 everything looks different and I spent hours but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New menu item has to be put into `<your_module_name>.links.menu.yml` file in the module folder. As an example here is definition of `Content` menu in file `system.links.menu.yml`:

```
system.admin_content:
  title: Content
  description: 'Find and manage content.'
  route_name: system.admin_content
  parent: system.admin
  weight: -10
```

In your case it would some something like this:

```
mymodule.my_module_settings:
  title: MyModule
  description: 'MyModule settings'
  route_name: mymodule.settings
  parent: system.admin
  weight: -10
```

(You should put this code in your new *.links.menu.yml file just modify route and other parameters according to your needs.)

The `route_name` route has to be defined in *.routing.yml file

```
mymodule.settings:
  path: 'mymodule/form/'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Form title'
    _form: '\path\to\your\form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Comment: Works like a charm, great answer. I will only add that we also need to clear the cache or (turn it off) to see the results.

Comment: How to add multi lingual menu item? From back-end menu items can be translated. How to do that in *.links.menu.yml file?